# Multi-Variable functions( Partial derivatives involved).

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

We're given :

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
      (x^{2}+y)\sin(\dfrac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}) & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
      0 & (x,y)=(0,0) \\ 
\end{cases} $$

We need to show that $f_x(0,0)=0$.

I found out the partial derivative as :

$f_x(x,y) = (2x)\sin(\dfrac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}) + (x^{2}+y)\cos(\dfrac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}})(\dfrac{-2x}{x^{2}+y^{2}})$.

But putting $(x,y)=(0,0)$ here ,  doesn't yield any result..

Could anyone guide me through this problem ?

Comment: IIT JAM huh?...

Comment: Nah.. Not exactly :P @TaylorTed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,
$$ f_x(x,y) = \lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}}.$$
In this case, we have
$$ f_x(0,0) = \lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}{\frac{(h^2+0)\sin\left(\frac{1}{h^2+0^2}\right) - 0}{h}}.$$
Take it from there...